# Pegar parte de uma string delimitada entre caracteres

Tags: php, string, concatenação-de-string

Tenho uma `string` como a do exemplo abaixo:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';
```

Minha dúvida é, como eu consigo pegar somente a parte do texto que está entre as barras `/`, e ao mesmo tempo retirar essa parte da `string` principal?

Teria que ficar tipo:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.';
$retirado = 'adipiscing elit';
```

Eu utilizei esse texto como exemplo, mas eu posso ter essa marcação com `//` em mais de uma parte da minha `string`, e precisaria pegar todas essas partes separadamente e retirar da `string` principal;

Exemplo:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum /dolor sit amet/, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';
```

Saída esperada:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum, consectetur.'
$retirado = 'dolor sit amet adipiscing elit';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php É isso que você quer!

Comment: Só tem um problema aí: `/, consectetur  /` também está entre barras.

Comment: O ideal neste caso é sempre você definir onde começa e onde termina.

Comment: Exatamente esse o problema, mas a string me vem assim.. Teria como ele identificar as // e mudar pra <> para todos por exemplo?

Comment: vc teria que ter uma string assim: Lorem ipsum [dolor sit amet], consectetur [adipiscing elit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar o `preg_match_all` quando existem múltiplos valores, [veja sua documentação aqui!](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php)

### Para "pegar":

> Isso é para SOMENTE obter os dados entre "/", dessa forma irá conseguir obter "o que tiver" entre os "/". Você conseguirá também usa-los para substituir. Como o sua postagem diz que necessita de "$string" e também o "$retirado", essa seria melhor solução.

```
// Sua string:
$string = 'Lorem ipsum /dolor sit amet/, consectetur /adipiscing elit/';

// Regex (leia o final para entender!):
$regrex = '/\/(.*?)\//';

// Usa o REGEX:
preg_match_all($regrex, $string, $resultado);
```

Você obterá exatamente, na variável $resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "/dolor sit amet/"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "/adipiscing elit/"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "dolor sit amet"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "adipiscing elit"
  }
}
```

Portanto pode fazer um:

```
foreach($resultado[1] as $texto){
  echo $texto;
}
```

Irá obter:

```
dolor sit amet
adipiscing elit
```

### Para remover:

**Usando o dado já obtido com o preg_match_all:**

> Isso é útil caso tenha necessidade de obter o dado usando o `preg_match_all`, dessa forma apenas irá substituir aquilo que já possui!

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum /dolor sit amet/, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';

$resultado = str_replace($resultado[0], "", $string);

echo $resultado;

// Retorna:
Lorem ipsum , consectetur .
```

**Usando o preg_replace:**

> Essa solução não responde totalmente a pergunta, pois o autor exige o "$retirado"!
>   
>   Para outros casos, quando apenas há necessidade de substituir, sem obter nenhum dado, pode usar tal método.

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum /dolor sit amet/, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';

$resultado = preg_replace('/\/(.*?)\//', "" , $string);

echo $resultado;

// retorna:
Lorem ipsum , consectetur .
```

**Sobre o REGEX:**

O Regex é o principal dessa função, portanto devo ao menos explicar minimamente.

```
/      Inicio do Regex!
\/     Escapa o "/" ("encontre a "/")
(.*?)  Obtenha qualquer caractere
\/     Escapa o "/" ("encontre a "/")
/      Fim do Regex (como estamos com o preg_match_all seria o mesmo de /g)
```

Dessa forma o REGEX executa algo como:

Encontre a "/", obtenha qualquer coisa até encontrar a próxima "/", assim obtendo tudo que está entre as "/".

Comment: E como recupero a parte original da string? Sem as partes em //? Posso usar o mesmo pra substituir também?

Comment: Editei para isso. Basta usar o `str_replace`, acho que inclusive já foi mencionado aqui e então usar a array. Veja a documentação em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php.

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso você pode usar umas das funções [split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.split.php) do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.split.php)

Uma das formas mais simples seria usando `explode()` que ficaria assim:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';
$pices = explode("/", $string);
//Array ( [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [1] => adipiscing elit [2] => . )
```

Nesse caso a função `explode()` gera um array com a string.

Além disso você pode usar as funções:
[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php)
ou
[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)

Nesse caso você usaria [expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)

Espero ter ajudado.

**update**

Para apresentar separadamente você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach ($pices as $key => $value) {
    echo "<p><strong>Pedaço $key: </strong>$value</p>";
}
```

Comment: Mas se eu tiver um caso com mais de uma parte contendo //, como vou saber usando explode qual parte do array pegar?

Comment: O explode vai te gerar um **array**. Caso queira manipular você pode fazer um **foreach** ou algo do tipo. Depois de separado os dados o que você faria com eles ? Não ficou muito claro a finalidade.

Comment: Eu separo os dados para apresentar em campos diferentes

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra ver se fica mais claro

Comment: É como você disse. Você pode ter um, dois ou dez pedaços. Com isso tem que fazer de forma dinâmica. Vou acrescentar o código de apresentação pra ver se te ajuda.

Comment: `split()` foi depreciada e removida.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o preg_replace, como mostrado a seguir:

```
preg_replace("/\/(.*\//", "", $string);
```

Comment: Não funcionou..

Answer (score 1):

function split_me($string,$start,$end){

$str2 = substr(substr($string, stripos($string, $start)), strlen($start));
$b = stripos($str2, $end);
return trim(substr($str2, 0, $b));
}

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';
echo split_me($string,'/','/');

Comment: Não funcionou..

Answer (score 1):

Experimente fazer assim:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum /dolor sit amet/, consectetur /adipiscing elit/.';

function removeParseContentBar($string)
{
    $arr = str_split($string);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $k => $char) {
        if ($char == '/') {
          /* abre a tag na primeira barra e
             fecha o elemento em tag quando 
             achar a segunda barra */
          $arr[$k] = ($i % 2 == 0) ? '<' : '/>';
        } else {
          $arr[$k] = $char;
          $i++;
        }
        $i++;
    } 
    $content = implode('', $arr);
    //remove a tag
    return strip_tags($content); 
}
echo removeParseContentBar($string);
```

[**Veja funcionando aqui**](https://ideone.com/atGtbj)

Comment: Ele funciona pra retirar quando tem só uma parte marcada, mas se tiver mais de uma como coloquei na pergunta ele tira partes a mais...

Comment: Editei, @FleuquerLima, agora acredito que vai fazer exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Seu código antigo usando o REGEX: `/\/(.*?)\//` ao invés de `/\/.*\//i`, funcionaria. Veja aqui: https://ideone.com/d44tyU